# Print greatest factor if it is same for both numbers

Tags: python, python-3.x, mathematics, factors

Take input n1 and n2 and check if they have the same greatest factor. If they do, print that factor. If they don't, print "No".

example:
input:
6
9
output:
3

input:
15
27
output:
No

```
n1=int(input())
n2=int(input())
l1=[]
l2=[]
for i in range(1,n1):
    if n1%i==0:
        l1.append(i)
        l1.sort(reverse=True)
cf1=l1[0]
for j in range(1,n2):
    if n2%j==0:
        l2.append(j)
        l2.sort(reverse=True)
cf2=l2[0]
if cf1==cf2:
    print(cf1)
else:
    print("No")
```

Comment: Your code is not finding the greatest common factor. It's finding if the greatest factors of the two numbers are equal.  The usual way to find the greatest common factor is the Euclidean algorithm.

Comment: The GCF of 15 and 27 should be 3. I've voted to close this question, since we only review code that is working correctly on this site.

Comment: @200_success no, we have to check if the greatest is same or not. for 15 it is 5 and for 27 it is 9 so not equal

Comment: @Teepeemm how to use euclidean algorithm?

Comment: Sorry, I misinterpreted "common greatest factor" as "greatest common factor". I've edited the post to remove that confusion, and retracted my close vote.

Comment: @200_success it's okay and thank you :D

Comment: The Euclidean algorithm is usually implemented along the lines of `gcf(a,b)=gcf(b,a%b)` and then recursing (or with a while loop).  But that's not what your code is doing (if that's what it's supposed to be doing, then you've misinterpreted your requirement).

Comment: (I'm somewhat ill at ease with the problem statement not explicitly excluding a natural number as its own factor.)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

At any point, 1 is always common factor of any two numbers. Your code works perfectly. But if you want to write a shorter code, check the condition if both numbers are divisible by any number using for loop going from range 2 (1 is always factor) to min of both numbers. Take a new variable f which is `False` initially. If the condition is satisfied i.e. if both nos are divisible by a no, change f to `True`. Then, out of the loop, write an if condition, if f==True then print the number or else the condition was never satisfied and f is False and print "no". Your code:

```
n1=int(input("Enter n1"))
n2=int(input("Enter n2"))
f=False
for i in range(2,min([n1,n2])):
    if n1%i==0 and n2%i==0:
        g=i
        f=True
if f:
    print(g)
else:
    print("no")
```

Comment: This is a (slow) implementation of finding the greatest common factor, but that's not what OP's code dos.

Comment: (Ignoring not checking factors higher than any common ones: How about `for i in range(min([n1,n2])//2, 1, -1):` ?)

Answer (score 1):

Quick and easy changes:

- `input` should prompt what it's asking for.
- You want to encapsulate what you're doing into a function, but the function should just return, not print.  But it's strange for a function to sometimes return a string and sometimes a number, so I've made it only return a number, and saved switching to "No" for the main thread to decide.
- You should document what you're doing and why.  Since there's been some confusion about the greatest common factor, you should definitely document that this isn't that.  Type hints are also nice.  I've also included some doctest entries, so that you could run `python -m doctest -v myscript.py` and double check that it's working.
- Use an `if __name__ == '__main__'` guard
- The only point of `l1` is to get the first number.  We can skip the reversing and just get the last number: `cf1=l1[-1]`.

A much better change comes from realizing that factors come in pairs (with a square root paired with itself).  This means that the greatest factor pairs with the least factor greater than 1:
`cf1 = n1/next( n for n in range(2,n1+1) if n1%n==0 )`
We could do the same thing for `cf2`, which would make the function symmetric and easier to understand.  But if we're desperate for that last performance boost, we can do a bit better:

If they have a common greatest factor, then it will be the greatest common factor.  The Euclidean algorithm will very quickly find this value.  The only thing that could mess things up would be if there is some other factor between `cf` and `n`.  That could be a lot of numbers to check, but we can do the pairing trick again, and look for other numbers between `1` and `n/cf`.  If there's a factor there, then there is a greater factor than the greatest common factor, and they don't have a common greatest factor.

```
def commonGreatestFactor(n1:int,n2:int) -> int:
    '''
    Finds if the greatest factor of each number is the same, and returns it.
    This is not the greatest common factor
    (although if they have the same greatest factor, then it is equal to the gcf).
    If they do not share the same greatest factor, this returns 0.
    
    >>> commonGreatestFactor(3,6)
    0
    >>> commonGreatestFactor(6,9)
    3
    >>> commonGreatestFactor(12,18)
    0
    >>> commonGreatestFactor(15,27)
    0
    '''
    gcf,other = n1,n2
    while other:
        gcf,other = other,gcf%other
    if min(n1,n2)==gcf<max(n1,n2):
        return 0
    # if there's a factor of n1 between 1 and n1/gcf,
    # then the gcf is not the greatest factor of n1
    if next( (n for n in range(2,n1//gcf) if n1%n==0) , 0 ):
        return 0
    if next( (n for n in range(2,n2//gcf) if n2%n==0) , 0 ):
        return 0
    return gcf

if __name__ == '__main__':
    n1=int(input('First number: '))
    n2=int(input('Second number: '))
    result = commonGreatestFactor(n1,n2)
    if result:
        print(result)
    else:
        print("No")
```

Comment: Let's try some more inputs - a) 6, 3 b) 12, 18.

Comment: @greybeard My comment was using `n` for `n1`, not for the index of the range (which wasn't a good idea on my part).  It was getting (12,18)->0, as it should, but it was missing (3,6)->0, which I've fixed.  Thanks.

Comment: (if `min(n1,n2)==gcf`, `gcf<max(n1,n2)` ↔ `n1 != n2`: `if n1 != n2 and min(n1, n2) == gcf`:) I'm not quite sure what the result of a) should be - but  shouldn't it be consistent with c) 6, 6? c) seems to call for 3 (exclude n1/n2) or 6 (allow). (similarly for d) 2, 3: is "the other trivial factor" allowed? students' code does.) (Don't quite know what I was thinking of suggesting b) (missed 9 as a divisor).) There's [math.gcd()](https://docs.python.org/3/library/math.html#math.gcd).

Comment: Seeing several places where it would be great to know n1 was no smaller than n2, I might assure that upfront (possibly handling n1==n2 as a special case). Then, I could use `(n for n in range(2, n2//gcf) if n1%n==0 or n2%n==0)` followed by `range(n2//gcf, n1//gcf) if n1%n==0`.

Answer (score 0):

"The `sort()`s" would work just fine called *once each* - *after* the loops.
Instead of `l1.sort(reverse=True)`, you could just use
`l1 = list(reversed([1, 2]))`. Or omit permuting the lists and just pick the highest factor:
`factor1 = l1[-1]`
(Building the lists using
`l1.insert(0, trial_divisor)` followed by `factor1 = l1[0]` is worse.)

But when wanting greatest factors, only, why accumulate complete lists?

```
def greatest_factor(n):
    """ Given a natural number n, return its greatest factor below n."""
    if n % 2 == 0:
        return n // 2
    for trial_divisor in range(3, int(math.sqrt(n)) + 1, 2):
        if n % trial_divisor == 0:
            return n // trial_divisor
    return 1
```

(Consider defining `smallest_factor()` (exceeding 1) and using that for `greatest_factor()`.)

(For a sane way to check for a *common greatest factor* as defined in the problem statement, [Teepeemm's answer](https://codereview.stackexchange.com/a/269313/93149)'s first revision just needs a bit of tying up loose ends.)